# Can you do peer to peer calls with Twilio?

Tags: twilio

If I wanted to create an interoffice phone system with Twilio can you call between two registered clients on Twilio, i.e. can I call my co-worker in the office across from me?

Bonus prize, if you can do that, can you enqueue the call to the other person, essentially creating a multi-line phone for people?

Thanks!

Comment: ? http://ricochen.wordpress.com/2012/10/07/using-twilio-without-a-public-web-server-howto/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Sure, you can absolutely make a Client to Client call.  The Twilio Client for JavaScript Quickstart has a walk-through showing you how to do this:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client/browser-to-browser-calls

You can also use the Queue verb in a client-to-client call.

Lets say you want to put Call A (lets call them 'customer') into a queue.  To do that you would create a new TwiML App and point it at a URL that returns the `<Enqueue>` verb.  When you initiate that client you would use that TwiML Apps SID to generate the Capability token.

Now for Call B (lets call them 'agent').  If you want to connect them to callers in your Queu, you would create another TwiML app whose URL returns TwiML with the `<Dial>` verb containing the `<Queue>` noun.  This tells Twilio to connect the 'agent' with the first caller in the queue.  As with the 'customer', when you initialize the 'agent', you would use the 'agent' specific TwiML App SID to generate the Capability token.

Hope that helps.

Devin

Comment: You've given me answers by breaking the problems into components, but I need to do both of them, so first call from one client to another, but instead of just accepting the call on the other side I want to queue that call. the Twilio.Connection object only seems to let me reject, connect, or ignore, not Queue. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: The queue does not happen on the Client side, which is why there is no API for it.  Call A uses the connect() method to make a connection into Twilio.  Twilio is going to make an HTTP request to whatever URL you have configured for your TwiML app.  That URL should return to Twilio the <Enqueue> verb which tells Twilio to put Call A into a call queue.  All of this happens before Call B even comes into the picture.  In fact Call A can sit in that queue all on its own without Call B even existing.

Comment: Now to 'dequeue' Call A, Call B needs to connect to Twilio and when Twilio makes its HTTP request to whatever URL you have configured for the 'agent' part of this workflow, that URL should return TwiML dial the <Dial> verb containing the <Queue> noun.  That connects Call B to whoever the first call in the queue is, which in this simple scenario is Call A.

Comment: Does that help?  If not we can take this to email.